# how to suppress the enoying dialog boxes when developing xPages?

Tags: eclipse, dialog, xpages, xsp

Anyone know how to remove or supress the enoying dialog boxes when developing xPages
If you are just making small xpages application you might not see these very often, but the more complex your xPages get you see these all the time. specially when you navigate your xpage using the outline view or during build

I click the x several times every day to get rid of it, Not sure if the operation quits when I click the x or if it continues in the background.

I would like a setting to get rid of it once and for all

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your designer, you should disable Build automatically in the Project menu. This will remove the constant build, but also means that you have to build manually, when needed.

You could also take a look at Nathan T. Freeman's post on the matter @ [Making Domino Designer work like you want](http://ntf.gbs.com/nathan/escape.nsf/d6plinks/NTFN-8GP6RP)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any java libraries added to the webinf/lib dir in your nsf? I noticed that when adding any jar files to the lib dir rebuilding your application can take ages..

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 external jar files used in my project (contained within the database). It used to take around **5-10 minutes to compile the project**. Any changes to the XPages/Custom Control/Java files needs a recompile. And you can imagine the frustration I had with the compilation time. Later I detached the jar files and put under the jvm\lib\ext folder. The compilation time drastically reduced to 1 minute. Still not happy.

As a next step, took a local replica of the database and started making the changes and recompilation on the local replica. Once done, replicated the databases and always previewed the changes on the server version. The compilation time is hardly 10 seconds. So **10 minutes to 10 seconds** :)

Comment: There is always serious overhead in accessing embedded Jars in the NSF, both at the design and client/server level. The recommendation is to always drop them into the lib/ext folder, unless the agent is unlikely to be executed often and the jars are small.

Answer (score 0):

Switch off build automatically, it will solve most of these.

There is also a known issue SPR SODY8Q9KNA where Java Design elements (new feature in 8.5.3) keep getting rebuilt on designer start up. That brings up the same pop-up.

There should be a fix for that in 8.5.3FP1 but I am not in an official position to say it will be in FP1 until it actually ships. You can check in the release notes as they are updated.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/r5fixlist.nsf/(Progress)/853%20FP1